# c strptime warning comparison between pointer and integer

Tags: c, strptime

Compiling with gcc 4.4.3 on Ubuntu 10.04.2 x86_64 I get the following warning:

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
```

for this line:

```
if (strptime(date_time, "%d-%b-%y %T", &tm) == NULL) {
```

If I change NULL to 0 the warning goes away. But the man page for strptime states that it returns NULL on error. I am including `<time.h>` with `#define __USE_XOPEN 1` on the previous line. I have also tried `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE`.

Thank you for your time.

EDIT

The full includes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define __USE_XOPEN 1 /* needed for strptime */
#include <time.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "recv.h"
#include "tcp.h"
#include "types.h"
```

EDIT

The following code gives the same warning:

```
#define __USE_XOPEN 1 /* needed for strptime */
#include <time.h>

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    struct tm tm;
    char date_time[] = "3-May-11 12:49:00";

    if (strptime(date_time, "%d-%b-%y %T", &tm) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: strptime failed matching input\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT EDIT

But changing it to _XOPEN_SOURCE worked! And moving the define to the top of the program fixed the original.

Comment: what is stored in `date_time`?

Comment: Hello, Patrick. Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you please edit your question by adding (to the bottom) a [Short, Self-contained, Compilable Exampe](http://sscce.org)?  If you were to post a 10-line program that invokes this warning, we would be able to tell you instantly what the problem is. Without such a program, we are mostly just guessing.

Comment: Your `#define __USE_XOPEN` (which you shouldn't use) is not **before any header** as it should. It must appear before `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: @Rob: Sure, I'll try to put one together.

Comment: Do not `#define __USE_XOPEN`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[edited after posting of complete includes-block]

You're using the wrong feature-selection macro and you're doing it in the wrong place.
`#define __USE_XOPEN 1` only works when glibc does it internally, not when you do it.
`#define _XOPEN_SOURCE` is what you're supposed to use, but it only works if you put it before *all* `#include`s of system headers.

Also, your code shows poor style: explicit comparison to NULL (or 0) inside an `if` is a bad code smell.  You should write it like this:

```
if (!strptime(...))
```

Also also, reasonable people can disagree with this, but I don't believe in using NULL at all.  In C, 0 is a perfectly good null pointer constant except under *very unusual* conditions -- and under those conditions *NULL doesn't work either*.  (Things are different in C++.)

Comment: However the warning he's getting is an indication that `strptime()` isn't being prototyped - I think he wants get to the root cause of the warning instead of avoiding `NULL` here.

Comment: `strptime` isn't one of the functions that causes actual problems if you use it like this without a prototype.

Comment: Actually it does. Any use of a function with the wrong declaration results in undefined behavior, and missing declarations are not even valid compilable C with C99.

Comment: @Zack - without a protoype, you risk calling with incorrect parameters.  Even if you call with correct parameters, you can't reliably use the return value on some platforms (such as the x86_64 platform discussed in the question) because half of the pointer being returned is lost when converted to `int`.  Granted, if you're just using it as an operand to `!` you'd be very unlucky if it returned a non-NULL pointer that had a lower half that happened to be `0`, but stranger bugs have occurred in the real world. And with a prototype, the possibility of that particular problem goes away.

Comment: @R That level of pedantry is quite inappropriate for a basic question like this one.  @Michael Good point about the pointer getting truncated to `int`, I hadn't thought of that.  Too much time spent with ILP32 systems.

Comment: Thank you for all the replies! I chose this one because it lists the two problems I think were causing the warning at the beginning of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

According to [POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html), `strptime` is declared in `<time.h>`.

You need

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
/* other headers, if needed, after the #define
#include <assert.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
*/
#include <time.h>
```

to have a correct prototype in scope.

Without a prototype, the compiler assumes functions return a `int`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the question. I have `#include <time.h>`

Comment: Oh @Patrick ... you've added the comment while I edited. The `#define`s need to come before any `#include`; not just before the function usage.

Comment: Never define `__USE_XOPEN`. It's an implementation-internal macro used in glibc `features.h` to implement `_XOPEN_SOURCE` and other feature test macros' behavior. Defining it yourself is not only nonportable, but could break things.

Comment: Thanks @R.., option removed for the comment in my post

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you are getting that warning because `strptime` isn't declared. (Without a declaration, `strptime` defaults to returning an `int`.) As you have already guessed, this is probably due to a missing `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE`.

The following program produces no warnings, using "gcc" on Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS. Is this what your program looks like?

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <time.h>

int main() {
  struct tm tm;
  char date_time[] = "Monday morning";
  if (strptime(date_time, "%d-%b-%y %T", &tm) == NULL) {
  }
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
You must not define __USE_XOPEN. You must define _XOPEN_SOURCE. From the linux man page, the correct usage is :

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <time.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. compare it with 0.
if strptime(date_time, "%d-%b-%y %T", &tm) == 0